# MPAndroidChart PieChart changing size after click event

Tags: android, kotlin, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am making an app which shows data in PieChart. In short, I have several charts. I am showing charts after choosing them from custom spinner. The problem is that when I choose PieChart from the spinner, everything works fine, but when I choose the same chart from the spinner again the size of the chart is changed a little bit.

I have tried to change the size of the form, but I think that problem is somewhere else

**MainActivity**

var popUpMenu: PopupMenu = PopupMenu(this, imageButton)

```
    popUpMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.array, popUpMenu.menu)
    popUpMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        textViewStatName.setText(it.title.toString())
        textViewStatNameLabel.setText(it.title.toString())
        val itemId= it.itemId
        val chartMethods: ChartMethods = ChartMethods()
        if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_1) {

        }
        else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_2) {
            val lineChart: LineChart = findViewById(R.id.lineChart)
            barChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            pieChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            lineChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            chartMethods.lineChart(this,2,lineChart)

        }
        else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_3)
        {
            val barChart: BarChart = findViewById(R.id.barChart)
            lineChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            pieChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            barChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            chartMethods.barChart(this,3,barChart)
        }
        else if(itemId == R.id.menu_item_4)
        {
            val pieChart: PieChart = findViewById(R.id.pieChart)
            lineChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            pieChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            barChart.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            chartMethods.pieChart(this,pieChart)
        }
        true
    }
    popUpMenu.show()
```

**chartMethods**

```
fun pieChart(context: Context, pieChart: PieChart)
    {
        val dbMethods: DBConnection = DBConnection()
        val request: String = dbMethods.getStatistics(4)
        var arrayList: ArrayList<PieEntry> = ArrayList()
        var typedArrayList = request.split(",").toTypedArray()
        typedArrayList = typedArrayList.dropLast(1).toTypedArray()
        var items = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
        var xAxisValues = ArrayList<String>()


        for (i in 0 until typedArrayList.size)
        {
            var helper : String = String()
            items  += typedArrayList[i].split("-").toTypedArray()
            if(items[i][1].contains(":")) {
                helper = items[i][1].substring(0, items[i][1].indexOf(":", 0, true)) + "." +
                        ((items[i][1].substring(items[i][1].indexOf(":", 0, true)+1)
                            .toInt())/6).toString()
                items[i][1] = helper
            }

            else {
                helper = items[i][1]
                items[i][1] = helper
            }

            xAxisValues.add(items[i][0])
        }
        var clearedNameList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        for (i in 0 until typedArrayList.size)
        {
            if(!clearedNameList.contains(items[i][0])) {
                clearedNameList.add(items[i][0])
            }
        }

        var fullCountedList = arrayOf<Array<String>>()
        for(i in 0 until clearedNameList.size)
        {
            fullCountedList += (clearedNameList[i] + "-" + "0").split("-").toTypedArray()
            for(j in 0 until typedArrayList.size)
            {
                if(fullCountedList[i][0] == items[j][0])
                {
                    fullCountedList[i][1] = (fullCountedList[i][1].toFloat() + items[j][1].toFloat()).toString()
                }
            }
        }

        var legendLabels: List<LegendEntry> = ArrayList<LegendEntry>()
        for(i in 0 until fullCountedList.size)
        {
            arrayList.add(PieEntry(fullCountedList[i][1].toFloat(), fullCountedList[i][1].toFloat()))
            val entry = LegendEntry()
            entry.formColor = ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS.get(i)
            entry.label = fullCountedList[i][0]
            legendLabels += entry
        }

        var pds: PieDataSet = PieDataSet(arrayList, "")
        pds.colors = ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS.toList()
        pds.valueTextSize = 10f
        var pieData: PieData = PieData(pds)
        pieChart.data = pieData
        pieChart.description.text = ""
        pieChart.legend.isEnabled = true
        pieChart.legend.setCustom(legendLabels)
        pieChart.legend.position = Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART_CENTER
        pieChart.legend.textColor = Color.WHITE
        pieChart.data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        pieChart.isEnabled = true
        pieChart.invalidate()
        pieChart.refreshDrawableState()
    }
```

**XML**

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/statFromSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/názovStatistikyLABEL"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/názovStatistikyLABEL"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
```

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: might be better to raise this as an issue on github as well

Comment: Issue on github [LINK](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4641)

Comment: don't get me wrong, i'm not saying this is a bad question or anything, it's just usually faster and easier to talk with the library owners :D hope you find an answer

Comment: yes you are right, but maybe there are people who encountered something like this and found out how to deal with it. And maybe when I find a solution and post it here, someone might think it is a handy solution :)

Comment: did you end up figuring out this problem? because I'm facing it myself now

Comment: @flash I am sorry I don't remember how I managed to fix this. Either I chose another chart or I've put it into a different layout. Sorry for not helping you more :(